# Tkinter keeps creating embedded plots instead of updating the current plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, refresh

I am aware that there are couple of questions on this around the web but unfortunately none of those helped me with this. My relevant matplotlib imports are:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

Below is how I call for new plots:

```
self.myFig1  = Figure(figsize = (10, 4), tight_layout = True)
self.myPlot1 = self.myFig1.add_subplot(111)
self.myPlot1.plot([blah],[blah])
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.myFig1, self.myFrame)
canvas1.show()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid()
```

I have a refresh button that sort of keeps calling the function that ends up creating this plot, but I need one embedded plot which is updated after every button click, not recreated. I have tried things like `Figure.close(), Figure.clf()` but none worked. I'd appreciate your help with this.

Additional info: The reason it keeps creating a new plot is because I keep .grid-ing it over and over again. So I deleted the .grid() part of the code and I tried something like this below which did not work:

```
self.myFig1.clf()
self.myFig1  = Figure(figsize = (10, 4), tight_layout = True)
self.myPlot1 = self.myFig1.add_subplot(111)
self.myPlot1.plot([blah],[blah])
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.myFig1, self.myFrame)
canvas1.draw()
```

This just destroys the figure, canvas, everything and doesn't plot anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.myFig.clear()
    self.myPlot = self.myFig.add_subplot(111,  **self.nadalkwArgs)
    self.myPlot.plot([series1], [series2])
    self.myFig.canvas.draw()
```

Is what solved my problem. Your "refresh plot" button or method should have this in order to keep the canvas, clear the old plot, make the new plot and keep plot style elements such as xlabel, ylabel etc. So basically, first you **clear the figure**(not the subplot, self.myPlot.clear() would clear the plot but you can't have your kwargs that way), and then you recreate the subplot with kwargs and then you plot, and finally you .canvas.draw()

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to recreate a new canvas or fig.
After grid your FigureCanvasTkAgg,  you can reset line in button callback only  by:

```
self.myPlot1.set_data(xdata,ydata)
self.myFig.canvas.draw()
```